# do I make this method work. The goal is to create a new set or array in which each element in the original set is multiplied by 2

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
def new_array(nums)
  i = 0
  double = []
    
  while i <= nums.length
    new_array = double[i] * 2
    double << new_array 
    i += 1
  end 
  return double 
    
end 

puts new_array[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Please add the description of the problem in the content of the post (and not just in the title)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to create a new `array` with each value multiplied by 2.

```rb
def array_times_two(original_array)
  original_array.map { |n| n * 2 }
end

array_times_two([2, 4, 6, 8])
=> [4, 8, 12, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_array = double[i] * 2
```

You are mixing up your variables. `new_array` is not an array, it is the name of your method. `double` is an empty array, so double[i] does not exist. Also, it loops once too many (the loop starts to count at zero). Try this:

```
  while i < nums.length # not  <=
    double << nums[i] * 2
    i += 1
  end
```

Futhermore, call your method like this: `puts new_array([2, 4, 6, 8])` , so with brackets (or put a space between the method and the argument), otherwise ruby itself will be mixed up.

Comment: wow thank you I had to take a look at my code after a break I see what I did wrong. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Doubling the elements of an array is better done using `map` or `map!` (depending on what exactly you want to achieve), but I guess you try to implement the algorithm in this hard way (without using the  Ruby core library) as a programming exercise, so I focus on your question why your approach does not work:

In your code, when you execute

```
new_array = double[i] * 2
```

double[i] is always `nil`, because you initialize `double` to the empty array and update it **later**, after the multiplication. You obviously can't multiply `nil` and will get an error message from this line.